# Setting Environment Variables on GCE (kubernetes)

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

Sorry for the noob question but from https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/release-1.1/docs/getting-started-guides/logging-elasticsearch.md
it says:

> To use Elasticsearch and Kibana for cluster logging you should set the
>   following environment variable as shown below:

```
KUBE_LOGGING_DESTINATION=elasticsearch
```

Where and how do I set this Env Var ? I was thinking that I should use

```
gcloud container clusters create
```

and pass the options there but there is no options...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That documentation is for users that are turning up clusters via the open source shell scripts for GCE. Elasticsearch isn't currently supported as part of the cluster creation commands for Google Container Engine. You can manually add it to your cluster after the cluster has been created.

Answer (score 13):

As already mentioned in Robert's answer the Elasticsearch/Kibana stack needs to be added manually if the cluster is supposed to run on Google Container Engine (GKE). Using the information given in this [post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-containers/Q1nvl8IAbqc), I was able to get it to work performing the following steps:

1. Start a GKE Cluster without cloud logging

   ```
   gcloud container --project <PROJECT_ID> clusters create <CLUSTER_ID> --no-enable-cloud-logging
   ```
2. Add a configured fluentd container to each running node by using a kubernetes DaemonSet.

   ```
   kubectl create -f fluentd-es.yaml
   ```

   **fluentd-es.yaml**

   ```
   apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
   kind: DaemonSet
   metadata:
     name: fluentd-elasticsearch
     namespace: kube-system
     labels:
       app: fluentd-logging

   spec:
     template:
       metadata:
         labels:
           app: fluentd-es
       spec:
         containers:
         - name: fluentd-elasticsearch
           image: gcr.io/google_containers/fluentd-elasticsearch:1.15
           resources:
             limits:
               memory: 200Mi
             requests:
               cpu: 100m
               memory: 200Mi
           volumeMounts:
           - name: varlog
             mountPath: /var/log
           - name: varlibdockercontainers
             mountPath: /var/lib/docker/containers
             readOnly: true
         volumes:
         - name: varlog
           hostPath:
             path: /var/log
         - name: varlibdockercontainers
           hostPath:
             path: /var/lib/docker/containers
   ```
3. Add elasticsearch and kibana pods and services.

   ```
   kubectl create -f es-controller.yaml
   kubectl create -f es-service.yaml
   kubectl create -f kibana-controller.yaml
   kubectl create -f kibana-service.yaml
   ```

   *Note below that the `kubernetes.io/cluster-service: "true"` label (present 
   in the original [files](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/master/cluster/addons/fluentd-elasticsearch)) has been removed.
   Having this label in the definitions resulted in termination of the running pods.*

   **es-controller.yaml**

   ```
   apiVersion: v1
   kind: ReplicationController
   metadata:
     name: elasticsearch-logging-v1
     namespace: kube-system
     labels:
       k8s-app: elasticsearch-logging
       version: v1
   spec:
     replicas: 2
     selector:
       k8s-app: elasticsearch-logging
       version: v1
     template:
       metadata:
         labels:
           k8s-app: elasticsearch-logging
           version: v1
           kubernetes.io/cluster-service: "true"
       spec:
         containers:
         - image: gcr.io/google_containers/elasticsearch:1.8
           name: elasticsearch-logging
           resources:
             limits:
               cpu: 100m
             requests:
               cpu: 100m
           ports:
           - containerPort: 9200
             name: db
             protocol: TCP
           - containerPort: 9300
             name: transport
             protocol: TCP
           volumeMounts:
           - name: es-persistent-storage
             mountPath: /data
         volumes:
         - name: es-persistent-storage
           emptyDir: {}
   ```

   **es-service.yaml**

   ```
   apiVersion: v1
   kind: Service
   metadata:
     name: elasticsearch-logging
     namespace: kube-system
     labels:
       k8s-app: elasticsearch-logging
       kubernetes.io/name: "Elasticsearch"
   spec:
     ports:
     - port: 9200
       protocol: TCP
       targetPort: db
     selector:
       k8s-app: elasticsearch-logging
   ```

   **kibana-controller.yaml**

   ```
   apiVersion: v1
   kind: ReplicationController
   metadata:
     name: kibana-logging-v1
     namespace: kube-system
     labels:
       k8s-app: kibana-logging
       version: v1
   spec:
     replicas: 1
     selector:
       k8s-app: kibana-logging
       version: v1
     template:
       metadata:
         labels:
           k8s-app: kibana-logging
           version: v1
           kubernetes.io/cluster-service: "true"
       spec:
         containers:
         - name: kibana-logging
           image: gcr.io/google_containers/kibana:1.3
           resources:
             limits:
               cpu: 100m
             requests:
               cpu: 100m
           env:
             - name: "ELASTICSEARCH_URL"
               value: "http://elasticsearch-logging:9200"
           ports:
           - containerPort: 5601
             name: ui
             protocol: TCP
   ```

   **kibana-service.yaml**

   ```
   apiVersion: v1
   kind: Service
   metadata:
     name: kibana-logging
     namespace: kube-system
     labels:
       k8s-app: kibana-logging
       kubernetes.io/name: "Kibana"
   spec:
     ports:
     - port: 5601
       protocol: TCP
       targetPort: ui
     selector:
       k8s-app: kibana-logging
   ```
4. Create a kubectl proxy

   ```
   kubectl proxy
   ```
5. Watch your logs with kibana at

   http://localhost:8001/api/v1/proxy/namespaces/kube-system/services/kibana-logging/

Comment: Do you know if it's possible to run two versions of fluentd, @Harry Haller. 1 for ELK and 1 for GCL.