# Change logging in a kubernetes cluster in gcloud to elasticserarch logging

Tags: kubernetes, gcloud

I have a kubernetes cluster in google cloud created by `cloud container clusters create` command. I want to use elasticsearch logging. How should I install "fluentd-elasticsearch" addon? Or where is another way?

Comment: there are 2 things you need to figure: can you access the kube-system namespace where these logging pods run? I doubt it, since it is used by GKE for their own logging. Are you able to run privileged containers? If you can run a privileged container, look at logspout https://github.com/gliderlabs/logspout to direct Docker logs to Logstash / Elastic

Comment: Found full answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34780553/setting-environment-variables-on-gce-kubernetes

Answer (score 0):

When launching the cluster you can disable the default logging to Cloud Logging by passing the `--no-enable-cloud-logging` flag. Once that is done you can install the [fluentd elasticsearch cluster addon](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/master/cluster/addons/fluentd-elasticsearch) from the Kubernetes repo.